# BufferError: Local: Queue full in Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka

```
import logging
from confluent_kafka import Producer
import os

logger = logging.getLogger("main")

BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = os.environ['BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS']
APPLICATION_ID = os.getenv('APPLICATION_ID', default = "nke-data-source")
RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS = os.getenv('RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS', default = 1000)
REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS = os.getenv('REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS', default = 40000)
ACKS = os.getenv('ACKS', default = "all")
RETRIES = os.getenv('RETRIES', default = 15)
RETRY_BACK_OFF = os.getenv('RETRY_BACK_OFF', default = 1000)
MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS = os.getenv('MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS', default = 1)
topic = os.getenv('OUTBOUND_TOPIC', default = "tti-nke-raw")

p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS, 
    'client.id': APPLICATION_ID, 
    'reconnect.backoff.ms': RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS,
    'request.timeout.ms': REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS,
    'acks': ACKS,
    'retries': RETRIES,
    'retry.backoff.ms': RETRY_BACK_OFF,
    'max.in.flight.requests.per.connection': MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS,
    'compression.type': "lz4"})

def send(key, event):
    try:
        logger.info("Sending key: [{0}] value: [{1}]".format(key, event))
        p.produce(topic=topic, value=event.encode('utf-8'), key=key)
    except Exception:
        logger.error("error sending events to kafka", exc_info=True)
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
BufferError: Local: Queue full
File "/app/sender.py", line 30, in send
p.produce(topic=topic, value=event.encode('utf-8'), key=key)
```

Can anyone help me in this as I'am new in python

Comment: Would you mind posting the entire traceback?

Comment: @DanielWalker Update also I think i have to updated my kafka queue size can you help me on that how to increase that

Comment: You may wanna try to increase `buffer.memory` (default 32MB), but a bigger question is why is it getting full.

Comment: IDK it is working fine and consuming the packet but somehow it is not empty ka queue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This `Queue` is something implemented in the `librdkafka` library (which `confluent_kafka` is binding to)

There is an inner `Queue` for the produce that takes the producer delivery report and waits for the produce to deal with them (mostly doing nothing), but you need to trigger this mechanism of going through the queue, which can be executed by calling `poll`

You should call `producer.poll(0)` after every call of produce
so change:

```py
p.produce(topic=topic, value=event.encode('utf-8'), key=key)
```

to:

```py
p.produce(topic=topic, value=event.encode('utf-8'), key=key)
p.poll(0)
```

Which will trigger the queue cleaning, don't worry about performance because this is a very simple function that doesn't really do much as the author of librdkafka wrote:

> poll() is cheap to call, it will not have a performance impact, so please add it to your producer loop.

basically it does:

> call poll() at regular intervals to serve the producer's delivery report callbacks.

consider to read about this in this [Issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/16) too

Answer (score 0):

It's either that or adding "queue.buffering.max.messages" to the initial Producer configuration. The latter works for me, for transactional tasks:

```
    producer = Producer(
        {
            "bootstrap.servers": <bootstrap-servers>,
            "compression.type": "gzip",
            "socket.timeout.ms": 1000,
            "api.version.request": True,
            "broker.version.fallback": "0.9.0",
            "transactional.id": <transactional-id>,
            "queue.buffering.max.messages": 10000000,  # 10M messages
            "logger": <logger>,
        }
    )
```